# Call web application from another web application

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to call a react web application to another javascript web application, I cannot use the iframe or the object, I cannot use the server require, and I don't know the frontend technologies that I will found, then I must use the basically technologies of every application ( javascript or jquery ).
I tried some ways to do it, for example in javascript

```
qr=new XMLHttpRequest();
qr.open('get',
    https://www.mywebapp.com/

    ,true);
qr.send('c1=v1&c2=v2');
qr.onload=function(){test2.innerHTML=qr.responseText}
```

and in jquery

```
var link = "https://mywebapp.com";
    var params = "c1=v1&c2=v2"
    $("#test").load(
        link,
        params,
        function(){alert("ciao")}
    );
});
```

also in jquery I have tried to use 
`ajax`,`ajaxSetup+ajax` and other way, in every way i tried to change the value of every parameter like `traditional true and false` or `content-type:'text/html'` or every parameter i have found the result of every tried was that I was loaded the page, but the page cannot find the static resources ( javascript, css, images ), I need help

Thank you

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking but it sounds like you want to include an external web application in to your own. IANAL but unless these applications are both owned/operated/run by the same person or organisation, I'd say you're on pretty dodgy legal ground trying to do this.

Comment: I have created a chatbot with react, now my client want integrate this chatbot in their application and I don't know the technology that they have, I know only that I canno use iframe and I cannot use the server side integration, but probably I must use the javascript to require this application in their application, I must integrate it from another server and another domain

Comment: `...but the page cannot find the static resources` that's because they're most likely using URLs relative to the location on the original domain. You will need to update those to absolute paths, or mirror the structure and content on your own domain.

Comment: You could use javascript to create a new window and direct that window to your website, running the chatbot. It won't be embedded into the website itself though. Have a look at `window.open()`. As far as I am aware you cannot do cross-domain requests with AJAX, so that won't work.

Comment: they want that the chatbot run into the page, I don't think that they want open the chat in another page, but the chat must be external that the domain and the server, I must find a way to use the application and his resources without use the iframes or objects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wow, after some clarification it sounds like the chatbot you have written needs to be embedded in to a page in another application. This way the chatbot doesn't know anything about the page it's being embedded on and the embedding page only needs a little bit of script to kick-start the loading of the chatbot.

You'll need to make sure you have JavaScript and CSS that can be downloaded from the chatbot server and dropped in to any page, regardless of which frameworks are in use.

Your JavaScript is then free to grab any other resources (HTML fragment/JavaScript/CSS/Images/etc.) as needed from the chatbot host. This is similar to how you would go about embedding [Disqus](https://help.disqus.com/installation/universal-embed-code) or [Google Maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial) on to a page.

I think helping implementing this is way out of scope for a single StackOverflow question but hopefully this will give you some idea of what is required and puts you on the right track.

Comment: I think yes, but I have created the application with a routing pattern, I can try to import in the second application, but the server probably will remind me in another source, the only way it could be open some access to static resources, but I don't like it because it's dirty and it seemed to me unsafe

Comment: Any calls to your chatbot host should really be AJAX/API calls with all of the client-side functionality already in the JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks, I think to understand